# How to verify ECDSA/SHA2 S-MIME signature with python?

Tags: python, security, cryptography, m2crypto

We need to choose between two signature schemes:

- RSA/SHA2 S-MIME signatures
- ECDSA/SHA2 S-MIME signatures

For that our python software needs to support one of this scheme. Currently for some political reasons the ECDSA solution is prefered.

Is the ECDSA solution supported by any of the python crypto modules (M2Crypto, ...) and do you have an example for that ?

The ECDSA support seems very young even for openssl.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ECDSA is supported](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/M2Crypto.EC-module.html) in [M2Crypto](http://chandlerproject.org/Projects/MeTooCrypto), but it can be optionally disabled. For example Fedora-based systems ship with ECDSA disabled in OpenSSL and M2Crypto. M2Crypto has some [SMIME support](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/M2Crypto.SMIME-module.html) as well, but since I haven't used it much I am not sure if that would be of help in this case. See the [M2Crypto SMIME doc](http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/doc/howto.smime.html) and [SMIME unit tests](http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/tests/test_smime.py), as well as [ec](http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/tests/test_ec_curves.py) [unit](http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/tests/test_ecdh.py) [tests](http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/tests/test_ecdsa.py).

Comment: thanks a lot Heikki, we will try that. Thanks also for maintaining the M2Crypto package. keep the good work

Comment: Heikki how do you change the digest algo in SMIME in M2Crypto. We would like to use SHA256 and I didn't find how to do that.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ecliptic Curve Cryptography (ECDSA) as well as the more common RSA is supported by the OpenSSL library.  I recommend using the [pyOpenSSL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyopenssl/) bridge.

Comment: Thanks Michael.
Have tried this scenario ECDSA/SHA256 as out of python, I saw lots of issues in the openssl mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the python ecdsa package, using Python3:

```
pip3 install ecdsa
```

Usage:

```
from ecdsa import SigningKey
sk = SigningKey.generate() # uses NIST192p
vk = sk.get_verifying_key()
sig = sk.sign(b"message")
vk.verify(sig, b"message") # True
```

To verify an existing signature with a public key:

```
from ecdsa import VerifyingKey

message = b"message"
public_key = '7bc9c7867cffb07d3443754ecd3d0beb6c4a2f5b0a06ea96542a1601b87892371485fda33fe28ed1c1669828a4bb2514'
sig = '8eb2c6bcd5baf7121facfe6b733a7835d01cef3d430a05a4bcc6c5fbae37d64fb7a6f815bb96ea4f7ed8ea0ab7fd5bc9'

vk = VerifyingKey.from_string(bytes.fromhex(public_key))
vk.verify(bytes.fromhex(sig), message) # True
```

The package is compatible with Python 2 as well